# Add customer orders count to orders grid

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

I'm trying to add customer total orders to orders grid in magento 1 admin. There is a lot of solutions already answered, but they all count orders only for registered customers and it is not working for guest orders.

I made my extension extending Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid.

In my _prepareCollection() I have joined sales_flat_order table so I can add customer email to my sales_flat_order_grid collection:

```php
protected function _prepareCollection() {

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    // Custom code
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
        'sales_flat_order',
        'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',
        array('customer_email')
    );

    // Here I'm missing code to add column orders_count to my collection 
    // with orders count by customer email address already joined to my collection

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();

}
```

I have tried with this code but it only works for registered customers, for guests customer_id is NULL:

```php
// Get orders count
$readAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$select = $readAdapter->select()
        ->from('sales_flat_order_grid')
        ->columns(array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)'))
        )->group('customer_id');
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$select.')')),
    'main_table.customer_id = orders_count.customer_id',
    array('orders_count.orders_count')
);
$collection->addFilterToMap('orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_count');
```

Hope somebody can help me with this problem.